# How to do delete specific data enter (saved in database) in ionic?

Tags: laravel, ionic3

I have created an API controller in the laravel. It did success. Data were able to be deleted. Now I try to create delete code in ionic. where when user clicked delete icon the data can be deleted from ionic and also to the database.

I changed the code to GET function in ionic code but it does not work which actually I can't find the solution yet.

here's what I have done in laravel which data were able to be deleted when testing api in postman.

**api.php**

```
public function deleteMed(Request $request) 
        {
            $id = $request->id;
            $medname = $request->medname;
            $price = $request->price;
            $stock = $request->stock;
            $medno = $request->medno;
            $ingredient = $request->ingredient;
            $description = $request->description;
            $addinfo = $request->addinfo;

             $user = AddMedicine::where('medno',  $request->input('medno'))->count();

             if($user!=0)
             {

                AddMedicine::where('id', $id)->delete([

                    'id' =>$id,
                    'medname'=>$medname,
                    'price'=>$price,
                    'stock'=>$stock,
                    'medno'=>$medno,
                    'ingredient'=>$ingredient,
                    'description'=>$description,
                    'addinfo'=>$addinfo,
                ]);

                $msg = "Data deleted"; 
                            $datamsg = response()->json([
                                'success' => $msg   
                            ]);  
                return $datamsg->content();
            }
            else{
                echo'{"error":{"text":" Medicine does not exist"}}';
            }
        }
```

Here is the code that I have done in ionic.

**viewMed.ts**

```
  //alert delete data
  confirmdelete() {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Confirm Delete',
    message: 'Do you confirm to delete?',
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Yes',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Yes clicked');
         this.deleteData(); // call deleteData()

        }
      }
    ]
  });
  alert.present();
}

  deleteData(){ 

    this.authService.deleteData(this.userData,'deleteMed').then((result) => {
      this.responsedata = result;
      if(this.responsedata.success){
          console.log(this.responsedata.success);
          localStorage.removeItem("userData");
          localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify({"id": this.responsedata.success}));
          //navparam
          this.navCtrl.push("ViewMedicinePage",({"id": this.responsedata.success}));
      }
      else
      {
          this.presentError(this.responsedata.error.text);
          console.log(this.responsedata.error);
      }
  }, (err) => {
    });
  }

  presentError(msg) { 
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
        message: msg,
        duration: 3000,
        position: 'bottom',
        cssClass: "withdraw_error"
    });

    toast.present(toast);
  }
```

I also create a delete function in authservice.ts in folder providers.

**authService.ts**

```
 deleteData(credentials, type){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let headers = new Headers();
            this.http.delete(apiUrl+type, JSON.stringify(credentials),
                {headers:headers}).subscribe(res => {
                    resolve(res.json()); 
            }, (err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
        });
      }
```

but at this code I got error on authservice.ts file
the error is expected 1-2 argument, but got 3

I want that the data can be deleted as user click the delete button and confirm delete. Then, the data delete updated in the laragon database.

Answer (score 0):

Delete request does not accept body params so if you want to pass body data try

```
let headers = new Headers();
const options = {
     headers: headers,
     body: credentials
}

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {         
     this.http.delete(apiUrl+type, options).subscribe(res => {
          resolve(res.json()); 
     }, (err) => {
           reject(err);
     });
 });
```

ref - https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-delete-request

Comment: the link that you send is for DELETE right but I use GET for API

Comment: you mentioned DELETE method in your authService.ts file. use this.http.get instead to this.http.delete otherwise you have to pass body like an above snippet.